# Bootstrap Carousel - how to disable right(next) button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have 2 radio buttons. (yes & No)

On clicking Yes -- Next button should be active (.btn-primary) [COLOR SHOULD BE BLUE]

On clicking NO -- p tag should be visible and next button should be disabled (it should be there, but will be inactive)

I'm able to make

tab visible..but not the btns

Link to [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRgVJ/9/)

```
$('#radio1').change(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#notes-sp').addClass('hide');
      }
    });
    $('#radio2').change(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#notes-sp').removeClass('hide');
        $('#show-plan').addClass('btn-primary');
        $('.right').attr('disabled','disabled');

      }
    });
```

Comment: You may operate on your id elements directly, instead of using `find`. `$('.radio').parent('div').find('#notes-sp').removeClass('hide');` --> `$('#notes-sp').removeClass('hide');`. Also, your radio `change` functions are outside of the `ready` function. Start by making those changes and it will help you clear your code a bit and put you on track.

Comment: I cleaned up the code a bit..Still couldn't disable/inactive the button

Answer (score 0):

When clicked on Yes Change the following in your code:

```
$('#radio1').change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.radio').parent('div').find('#notes-sp').addClass('hide');   
      $('#myCarousel').find('.right').css('background-color','#006dcc');
      $('#myCarousel').find('.right').addClass('btn-primary');
  }
});
```

When clicked on No Change the following in your code:

```
$('#radio2').change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#myCarousel').find('.right').css('background-color','#222222');
    $('#myCarousel').find('.right').addClass('disabled');
    $('.radio').parent('div').find('#notes-sp').removeClass('hide');
    $('.radio').parents('div').find('#show-plan').addClass('btn-primary');
    //$('.radio').parents('div').find('a[data-slide="next"]').addClass('btn-primary').removeClass('carousel-control:hover');
  $('.radio').parents('div').find('a[data-slide="next"]').attr('disabled','disabled').removeClass('carousel-control:hover');
  }
});
```

Comment: I added a mask..it kinda fixed the issues. Thanks